# Make opening 1 div close all other divs of same class (excluding itself) in JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write JQuery for a set of animated info boxes. Clicking on the title `div.info-box__title` should open the adjacent `div.info-box__content` and at the same time close any other open `div.info-box__content`

**Update** - should have specified, I also need ALL boxes to close when user clicks outside any `.info-box`.

**Update 2** - Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/q9orfsoy/

The markup is like this:

```
 <section id="info-box-3" class="info-box">
     <div class="centerer">
         <div class="info-box__close"></div>
         <div class="info-box__title">
             <h1>Title</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="info-box__content">
             <p>content</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I always struggle with execution order issues with JS. What I have so far are two functions:

Opening:

```
$('.info-box__title').bind("click touchstart", function() {

    // close the others and open this one
    if($(this).next('.info-box__content').css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).next('.info-box__content').slideDown();
        $(this).parents('.info-box').addClass('open');
        $(this).parents('.info-box.open').siblings().children('.info-box__title').hide();
    }
});
```

Closing:

```
// hide all when click anywhere else in the document
$(document).bind("click touchstart", function(event) {

    // exclude the one that's currently open
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.info-box.open').length){
        $('.info-box__content').slideUp(function(){
            $(this).parents('.info-box').removeClass('open');
        });
    }
});
```

What this code does is closes all the info-box__content divs when you click outside them. But if you click on another info-box__title it just opens that as well without closing the rest.

(Initially I thought adding a class of `.open` to the one that's opened would be enough, but I guess I've run into execution order issues?)

What's the best/recommended way to deal with something like this?

Comment: There is jquery ui accordion for this purpose [link](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: I need to do it without jQuery UI really...

Comment: What is expected result if title is clicked again, while content visible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index) , jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q9orfsoy/1/

```js
var titles = $(".info-box__title");
var content = $(".info-box__content");

titles.on("click touchstart", function(e) {
   if ($(this).next(".info-box__content")
       .is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next(".info-box__content")
      .slideUp()
   } else {
  content.slideUp()
  .eq($(this).index(".info-box__title"))
  .slideDown()  
   }
});
// ALL boxes to close when user clicks outside any `.info-box`
$(document).on("click touchstart", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is(".info-box, .info-box *")) {
    return
  }
  else {
    content.slideUp()
  }
})
```

```css
.info-box__content {
display: none;
}

.info-box {
border: 1px solid black;
padding; 20px;
margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
 <section id="info-box-1" class="info-box">
     <div class="centerer">
         <div class="info-box__close"></div>
         <div class="info-box__title">
             <h1>Title 1</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="info-box__content">
             <p>content</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
 <section id="info-box-2" class="info-box">
     <div class="centerer">
         <div class="info-box__close"></div>
         <div class="info-box__title">
             <h1>Title 2</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="info-box__content">
             <p>content</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
 <section id="info-box-3" class="info-box">
     <div class="centerer">
         <div class="info-box__close"></div>
         <div class="info-box__title">
             <h1>Title 3</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="info-box__content">
             <p>content</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get my code to work using this idea but struggling for some reason... let me make a fiddle.

Comment: @mike-source Tried jsfiddle.net/q9orfsoy/1 ? Added portion where `.slideUp` is called if content is visible and title is clicked again, which can be removed. Did not find logic at OP for condition: if content is open and title clicked again.

Comment: this is the solution I think I'll probably go with: https://jsfiddle.net/q9orfsoy/7/

I like the simplicity, I probably just made a bug re-formatting it into my style.

Comment: update: I used this in the end, but with just .on("click") for detecting clicks and touches... 'touchstart' just seemed to make things break on touchscreens (ironically), after coming back from a 4 day weekend I now no longer remember why I thought I needed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Close all then open the one you want with the this object.

```
$('.info-box__title').click(function() {
    $('.info-box__content').hide(); //or perform closing action
    $(this).siblings('.info-box__content').show(); //or perform opening action
});
```

To close when clicking outside of any info box,

```
$('body').not('.info-box').click(function() {
    $('.info-box__content').hide(); //or perform closing action
});
```

Comment: See edit to my question, I also need them all to close when clicking outside.

Comment: now this just opens and instantly closes itself... I'd prefer to stick with using $(document).bind() to do the closing, see: https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```js
 $('.info-box__title').click(function() {
    var sibling = $(this).siblings('.info-box__content');    
    if(!sibling.is(':visible')){
     $('.info-box__content:visible').slideUp();
        sibling.slideDown(); }
    else sibling.slideUp();
 });
$(document).bind("click touchstart", function(e)
{
    var open_content = $(".info-box__content:visible");

    if (!open_content.parent().is(e.target) 
        && open_content.parent().has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        open_content.slideUp();
    }
});
```

```css
.info-box__title{background:grey;}
.info-box__content{
height:100px;
  display:none;
background:red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="info-box-3" class="info-box">
     <div class="centerer">
         <div class="info-box__close"></div>
         <div class="info-box__title">
             <h1>Title</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="info-box__content">
             <p>content</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="info-box-4" class="info-box">
     <div class="centerer">
         <div class="info-box__close"></div>
         <div class="info-box__title">
             <h1>Title</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="info-box__content">
             <p>content</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="info-box-5" class="info-box">
     <div class="centerer">
         <div class="info-box__close"></div>
         <div class="info-box__title">
             <h1>Title</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="info-box__content">
             <p>content</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Good call on using siblings, I assumed content was a child element!

Comment: sorry, this type of method isn't what I was after, should have been clearer!

Comment: @mike-source I've added a solution to close the currently open content if clicked outside

Comment: @mike-source check the snippet

Comment: Ok, you added css styling for open/closed... sorry, my code was using jquery to animate. Technically correct and I could do it this way but I'm pretty sure I was really close with what I had in the first place.

Comment: @mike-source added jquery animations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74357/discussion-between-tkay-and-mike-source).

Comment: this looks like a good solution, but can't get it to work with my code, I need to use bind("click touchstart") for the click event, this is as far as I got with this one: https://jsfiddle.net/ey0L7wn6/3/ (changed 'event' to 'e', no difference)

Comment: @mike-source fixed that problem. check

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$(document).bind("click touchstart", function(event) {
  var $openBox = $(event.target).closest('.open');
  $('.info-box__content').not($openBox).slideUp(function(){
    $(this).parents('.info-box').removeClass('open');
  });
});
```

This will select all boxes other than the one related to the click event.

**Bonus explanation**

The reason your current solution doesn't work is that your just checking to see if the `open` box exists, since it does, it then closes all elements with the class `.info-box__content'. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: This makes the box open and then instantly close itself (I tried using var $openBox = $(event.target).closest('.info-box.open'); rather than just '.open' too)

Answer (score 0):

Easily slideUp all class while using **stop()** to slideDown() or slideToggle() target section:

```
$('.info-box__title').click(function() {
   $('.info-box__content').stop().slideUp();
   $(this).find('.info-box__content').stop().slideDown();
});

$('body').not('.info-box').click(function() {
   $('.info-box__content').stop().slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Would be a solution but this isn't what I'm asking (my fault for not being specific)

Comment: I added the code to close all tabs when click is outside of this class. I think Your key point is to use **stop()** before slideDown or slideUp.